# Estoy haciendo un login para un juego, cuando el jugador digita mal el nombre de usuario o la contraseña no lo vuelve a reconocer como correcto

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Si el jugador en una segunda, tercera, etc.. oportunidad digita el nombre de usuario o la contraseña bien no la reconoce como correcta ¿Cómo hago para que reconozca las entradas correctamente ya que solo lo hace la primera vez?

````
string nombreUsuario;
string txt = ".txt";
string nombreUsuarioTXT;
ifstream archivoNombreUsuario;
int contrasena; 
char contrasenaTXT[5];
char usuario[20];

int main(){
    verificarNombreUsuario();   
    
    return 0;
}
void verificarNombreUsuario(){
    cout << "\n\t\tBIENVENIDO A " << endl;
    cout << "\n\tIntroduce tu nombre de usuario: ";
    getline(cin, nombreUsuario);
    
    nombreUsuarioTXT.append(nombreUsuario);     
    nombreUsuarioTXT.append(txt);   

    archivoNombreUsuario.open(nombreUsuarioTXT.c_str(), ios::in);
    
    if(archivoNombreUsuario.fail()){ 
        cout << "\n\tEL USUARIO INGRESADO NO EXISTE. Por favor vuelve a intentarlo";
        Sleep(2000);
        verificarNombreUsuario();
    }
    else{
        cout << "\n\tHola" << endl;
    }
    archivoNombreUsuario.close();

}```

Esta es la parte del codigo donde hago el login
Lee un archivo de texto con cualquier nombre de no mas de 20 caracteres
````

Answer (score 1):

Si en algun momento aterrizas en otra de las muchas respuestas que he publicado en StackOverflow verás que comento que hay que reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible porque permite crear código más seguro y robusto. Pues bien, aquí tenemos un ejemplo muy claro.

Tu problema es que tienes una variable global llamada `nombreUsuarioTXT` que no inicializas a cada uso:

- primer intento: el usuario introduce `asdf`. `nombreUsuarioTXT="asdf.txt"`
- segundo intento: el usuario introduce `zzzxxx`. `nombreUsuarioTXT="asdf.txtzzzxxx.txt"`

Este efecto se produce porque concatenas todo el rato:

```
nombreUsuarioTXT.append(nombreUsuario);     
nombreUsuarioTXT.append(txt);
```

Si hubieses usado el operador `=` en vez de `append` o si la variable no fuese global sino local, el problema se habría solucionado por si solo, pero si ya partes de la base de declarar todas las variables globales ... ya tienes la mitad del problema creado:

```
void verificarNombreUsuario(){
    cout << "\n\t\tBIENVENIDO A " << endl;
    cout << "\n\tIntroduce tu nombre de usuario: ";
    
    std::string nombreUsuario;
    getline(cin, nombreUsuario);
    
    nombreUsuario += txt;     

    ifstream archivoNombreUsuario;

    // A partir de C++11 se puede usar open() con std::string
    archivoNombreUsuario.open(nombreUsuario, ios::in);
    
    if(archivoNombreUsuario.fail()){ 
        cout << "\n\tEL USUARIO INGRESADO NO EXISTE. Por favor vuelve a intentarlo";
        Sleep(2000);
        verificarNombreUsuario();
    }
    else{
        cout << "\n\tHola" << endl;
    }
    archivoNombreUsuario.close();
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "hay que reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible"?
No soy el que pregunta, pero me has suscitado la duda del qué es eso.

Comment: @Aaronibio una variable global vive mientras se ejecute el programa. Una variable local no está disponible todo el rato, solo existe en momentos puntuales. Una variable local es complicado o imposible reutilizarla, lo que tiende a evitar que acabemos usando valores sucios. Por otro lado, las variables locales ayudan a hacer un mejor uso de la pila del programa

Comment: Por esos motivos es conveniente limitar la vida de las variables. Si no es necesaria en un punto es preferible que esa variable no exista en dicho punto. Imagina que tienes tu mesa de trabajo. Será más cómodo trabajar si en la misma tienes los útiles que necesitas en cada momento. Si llenas la mesa con todas las herramientas que puedas llegar a usar durante todo el día tendrás poco espacio libre y será incómodo trabajar, aparte de que es más facil que te hagas daño o se rompa algo ... pues con las variables pasa exactamente lo mismo

Comment: muchas gracias, soy de poner pocas variables, pero alguna se me queda suelta por ahí.

Comment: @Aaronibio conforme tus programas vayan creciendo en complejidad y sean más ambiciosos, el número de variables crecerá igualmente. Por eso es importante adquirir buenos hábitos desde el principio